# Counting many to many association records

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have many to many association between `words` and `definitions`.

```
words:
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

definitions:
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| language_id       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

definitions_words:
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| definition_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| word_id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I would like to get all word records which have exactly one definition with `language_id = 1`.

Comment: Consider providing DDLs for the above (CREATE and INSERT statements) so that we don't have to.

Comment: Words.includes(:definitions).where(:language_id => 1) with something like has_many :definitions, :through => :definitions_words, :uniq => true

Comment: I don't want to create ActiveRecord instances because of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID, COUNT(*) totalRecordCount
FROM    words a
        INNER JOIN definition_words b
            ON a.ID = b.word_ID
        INNER JOIN definitions c
            ON b.definition_id = c.ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id,
                    SUM(language = 1) totalCount
            FROM    definitions
            GROUP   BY id
        ) d ON c.ID = d.ID AND 
               d.TotalCount = 1
GROUP   BY a.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to express this in SQL is using `in`:

```
select *
from words
where id in (select word_id
             from word_definitions
             where language_id = 1
             having count(*) = 1
            )
```

However, `in` with a subquery does not always work efficiently in MySQL.  It can be replaced with an `exists` clause:

```
select *
from words w
where exists (select 1
              from word_definitions wd
              where language_id = 1
              having count(*) = 1 and wd.word_id = w.id
             )
```